# Using attribute parameter as a form name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a generic form validatation indicator. If the form is valid, it displays saying that the form is valid, else it displays an error saying that the form isn't valid.

I'm using `bookingForm.$valid` or `SOMEFORM.$valid` - but the `ng-show` isn't working. I think the connection between `{{formValid}}`  and the actual form model isn't right.

**Here's my directive:**

```
sharedServices.directive('formValid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            formValid: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="!{{formValid}}.$valid"><b>ATH!</b> Útfylling ekki í lagi</div>' +
                    '<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="{{formValid}}.$valid"><b>OK!</b> Útfylling í lagi</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.formValid = attrs.formValid;
        }
    };
});
```

**Here's my usage:**

```
<div form-valid="bookingForm"></div>
<form name="bookingForm">...</form>

<div form-valid="contactForm"></div>
<form name="contactForm">...</form>
```

I want to pass the **form name** (model) into my directive's template and display accordingly whether $valid is true/false on the forms model. Do I need to compile the template or how can I accomplish this?

Here's a GIF showing that it doesn't work, `bookingForm.$valid` is correct in the HTML, but always false in the directive's template.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/j4g610g.gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ng-show` creates a new scope, you need access the form in the `$parent` scope. It's a bit tricky in terms of the model assignment. You can use `attrs.$observe` to assign the object instead of the value of `$valid`.

Please try this code:

```
sharedServices.directive('formValid', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            formValid: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="!formValid.$valid"><b>ATH!</b> Útfylling ekki í lagi</div>' +
            '<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="formValid.$valid"><b>OK!</b> Útfylling í lagi</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('formValid', function () {
                scope.formValid = scope.$parent[attrs.formValid];
            });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Df9FG/)**</kbd>